# JQuery Ajax function return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've defined a file availability.php that return "yes" or "no", well i have a form that must check availability of a form before subscribe a user, and i do this using this ajax function, but the compare line seems not work ?

```
        availability: function(element, value) {
          $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "/tunnel/availability.php",  
            data: "username="+element, 
            dataType: "html", 
            success: function(data){   
              $("#response").html(data);
              var $response = data;
              if ($response == "yes")
                 alert("found");
             }  
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
availability: function(element, value) {
  $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "/tunnel/availability.php",  
    data: "username="+element, 
    success: function(data){   
      if (data == "yes"){
         alert("found");
      }
     }  
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it's not working?  If you're expecting your function to check and return a value before a form is submitted, it is likely that the `availability` function is returning before the ajax check is performed, allowing your form to submit and nullifying the alert -- i.e., the page is already unloaded and the new request is being processed.  If you want to use this to check availability before submitting a form you'll need to:

1. Return false from `availability` (or otherwise stop the form submission)
2. Do the form submission from the `availability` success function.
3. (maybe) Indicate that you're expecting a text response instead of html.

You can also simplify the check -- there's no need to put "data" in a variable before you check it.  I'm also not sure why you are adding it to the page, but that could be reasonable.  I'd also suggest a name change for the function (if you modify it to do this) and handling the form submission via AJAX -- if not, you can remove the handler and simply trigger a submit on the form.

```
submitIfAvailable: function(form, element, value) {
  $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "/tunnel/availability.php",  
    data: "username="+element,
    dataType: 'text',  // I think it should work without this, but...
    success: function(data){   
      if (data == "yes"){
         $form = $(form);
         $.post( $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            // process the result of form submission
         });
      }
     }  
  });
  return false;
}
```

I'm making some assumptions -- modify as appropriate if this doesn't fit in with how the `availability` function is used.  The key thing to remember is that the function will return **before** the AJAX call completes and you can't use any return value from the function that comes from the AJAX call.  This is true, at least, if you don't force the AJAX call to run synchronously by setting the option `aSync` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm what the availability page is actually returning.
Debug the callback using Firebug (or your favourite JS debugger) to see what sort of object is returned as `data`. You might find that your return value is wrapped, eg you might have to check `data.value` or something similar.